# VS C++ Dead code elimination

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, static-linking, dead-code

I have a small project in C++ VS 2010, which uses a couple of static link libraries(.lib files).

This options are turned on: OPT:REF, OPT:ICF, /GL, GR-

When I add unused method to a class, which uses some code from static libraries, compiler generated bigger code(i.e. includes this method in final executable)

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it virtual, perchance? Just curious. (not going down the road of why you're adding unused code in the first place, as I'm sure you have   your twisted reasons).

Comment: Well, this code resides in a shared class file, which uses by multiple projects, and thats why I need dead code elimination. Method isn't virtual, just normal public method.

Comment: Any particular reason you're being anal about the .exe (or .dll) size?  How much of a size difference are we talking about? A few K?  A 100K?  1MB or more?  Just curious...

Comment: Difference is about 200 kb... This is just curiosity, cannot understand why compiler is doing this :\

Comment: Other options may conflict, /Gy could be turned off (it is off by default for member functions defined out of class declaration), class could be exported -- too many things to consider.

Comment: /Gy is turned on, and class isn't exported. Just a cpp/h file that included in several projects